# Is public disclosure of wealth prohibited in Islam? Is there any evidence in the sunnah?

Tags: hadith, reference-request, politics

> **ISLAM FORBIDS PUBLIC DISCLOSURE OF WEALTH: PAS**
>
> The tabling of motion [to compel members of parliament to declare their assets] met with objections from opposition MPs.
>
> PAS deputy president and Kubang Kerian MP Tuan Ibrahim Tuan Man told reporters at the parliament lobby that Islam does not allow people to publicly disclose their wealth due to security concerns.
>
> “In Islam, there is a hadith that says if god has given you wealth, do not declare it to the public as there are many observers,” he was quoted as saying by Malay Mail.
>
> Hadith refers to the records of the words of Prophet Muhammad.

[Source](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/asia/motion-to-compel-malaysian-mps-to-declare-assets-passed-pas-says-11679526)

I'm wondering if Tuan Ibrahim Tuan Man is correct.

Comment: its not a good idea to use a hadith to make anything halal/haraam, because you can never be certain the hadith is true or not. Unless there is sChOlArLy cOnSeNsuS of course.

Comment: @UbaidHassan Why? "Fight those who do not believe in Allah or in the Last Day and who do not consider unlawful what **Allah and His Messenger** have made unlawful and who do not adopt the religion of truth from those who were given the Scripture - [fight] until they give the jizyah willingly while they are humbled" *(9:29)* How will you go about finding what Allah's Messenger made unlawful without ahadith?

Comment: please re read my comment for “why” jazakallah

Comment: @UbaidHassan "How will you go about finding what Allah's Messenger made unlawful without ahadith?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that the charity we give is part of our wealth and Allah (ﷻ) said its OK to disclose that publicly. There are "observers" in this case of charity too but so long as our intentions are pure, we can disclose that information as per the guidance of Allah (ﷻ). By extension, we can conclude that there's nothing wrong with disclosing overall wealth if it serves a purpose/need.

> Qur'an 2:271 إن تبدوا الصدقات فنعما هي وإن تخفوها وتؤتوها الفقراء فهو خير لكم ويكفر عنكم من سيئاتكم والله بما تعملون خبير  If you disclose your charitable expenditures, they are good; but if you conceal them and give them to the poor, it is better for you, and He will remove from you some of your misdeeds [thereby]. And Allah, with what you do, is [fully] Acquainted.

I've not yet seen evidence that says otherwise.

Moreover, during his time as Caliph, Umar رضي الله عنه came to know of the wealth of Abu Hurairah رضي الله عنه whom he had appointed as governor.. and made him give 12,000 dirhams back to the public treasury ([read narration here](https://www.islamweb.net/womane/nindex.php?page=showfatwa&FatwaId=366526)) -- This is what modern day government officials fear.

Comment: Link updated: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/366526/incident-between-umar-and-abu-hurayrah-about-public-money